# Release() function in COM

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, com

Following is a main method of a c++ program.

```
int main(){

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IDataCollectorSet* pdcs = NULL;

    hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

    hr = CreateDCS(pdcs);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf(L"CreateDCS failed.\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    hr = AddDataCollector(pdcs);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf(L"AddDataCollector failed.\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    hr = SaveDCS(pdcs);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf(L"SaveDCS failed.\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    hr = pdcs->Start(VARIANT_TRUE);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf(L"pdcs->Start failed.\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    getchar();
cleanup:

    if (pdcs)
        pdcs->Release();

    CoUninitialize();


}
```

I do not understand what is done by "Release()" function within the "cleanup" tag. if Release() function can be called for a *pdcs shouldn't it be declared under IDataCollectorSet class? i can't find any function defined as "Release()" in their documentation.

Where is it declared and what is the purpose of this function?

Note: the included header files are

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <comutil.h>
#include <pla.h>
```

Comment: There is no `Release()` function "in C++", it is not part of the C++ standard. It is a COM function, so your title is somewhat misleading. I've edited the title now.

Comment: Thanks! i did not know about it when I posted the question

Comment: Why are you assigning two value to `hr` (S_OK and the result of `CoInitializeEx`) if you're always going to overwrite it with the result of `CreateDCS` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using a COM object, and the memory management of COM objects is a co-operative affair.

As the comsumer of a COM object it's your job to tell the COM object when you have finished with it. You do this by calling `Release`.

Inside the COM object it keeps a count of how many users have a reference to it. The reference is increased by calling `AddRef`, and decreased by calling `Release`. When the reference count gets to zero the object know that nobody else is referencing it and will clean up its memory. This is usually done by a call to `delete this` in the `Release` method.

It's essential that you call `Release` in the right places, otherwise you'l leak memory through the objects not being destroyed. Instead of using a raw COM pointer it's best to use a smart pointer such as [CComPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98.aspx) that will automatically call `Release` when the object goes out of scope, and will call `AddRef` when you pass the object around.

Answer (score 3):

Release is a method of [IUnknown COM interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which any COM object implements.

Its purpose is to ["decrement the reference count for an interface on an object"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When the reference counter drops to zero, the implementation of `IUnknown::Release()` must destroy the object.

Answer (score 1):

This Release is from IUnknown:

```
IUnknown::Release
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

COM interfaces inherits from it. Calling Release lowers reference count of COM object, eventually realeasing it.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing `IDataCollectorSet` but i guess it frees some ressources aquired by this class.